# SQL Query, get a columns if another columns equal to x

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table that is like this

```
 x      y  
10    5  
10    8  
10    12  
11    9  
11    14  
11    12  
14    12  
14    5  
14    11
```

I need to return all the x group that has the same value if y = 5
So I would need a query that would return me the x group that has the value 10 or 14.
Query:

```
select x, y from table ...
```

Should return me something like this :

```
x y  
10 5  
10 8  
10 12  
14 12  
14 5  
14 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select x, y
from your_table
where x in 
(
  select distinct x
  from your_table
  where y = 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE x in
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT x
        FROM tableName
        WHERE y = 5
    )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f50d5/1)

or a join can also solve it

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT x
            FROM tableName
            WHERE y = 5
        ) b ON a.x = b.x
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f50d5/3)