# SQL - Return all Rows Where at Least one has value 'Y'

Tags: sql, distinct

My question is very similar to this previous post
[SQL Query, get a columns if another columns equal to x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566218/sql-query-get-a-columns-if-another-columns-equal-to-x)

The only difference is I am joining two tables and the previous solution does not seem to work. Basically I have two Columns once the tables have been joined. I want all rows of a name, where at least one row for that name has "Shasta" as a location. For example,

Column 1 = Name (From Table 1)
Column 2 = Location (From Table 2)

```
Name   |  Location
-------------------
Bob    |   Shasta
Bob    |   Leaves
Sean   |   Leaves
Dylan  |   Shasta
Dylan  |   Redwood
Dylan  |   Leaves
```

Should Return:

```
Name   |   Location
--------------------
Bob    |   Shasta
Bob    |   Leaves
Dylan  |   Shasta
Dylan  |   Redwood
Dylan  |   Leaves
```

I tried the solution of the previous post

```
where x in
(
  select distinct x
  from table 1
  where y like 'Shasta'
)
```

Unfortunately, it only returned:

```
Name   |  Location
--------------------
Bob    |   Shasta
Dylan  |   Shasta
```

Comment: you need to give us your existing query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `WHERE EXISTS` clause. As an illustration, let's assume you have the following query:

```
select a.Name, b.Location
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.TableBId = b.Id
```

You are looking to retrieve all rows in this query **where** there **exists** a row in the same query results with that `Name` and where `Location = 'Shasta'`. Therefore we can use the query as a derived table, match the `Name` and look for a `Location = 'Shasta'`:

```
select a.Name, b.Location
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.TableBId = b.Id
where exists (
    select 1
    from
    (
        select a.Name, b.Location
        from table1 a
        join table2 b on a.TableBId = b.Id
    ) x --this is the same as the above query, as a derived table
    where x.Name = a.Name --correlate the queries by matching the Name
    and x.Location = 'Shasta' --look for the column value in question
)
```

Granted, you may be able to simplify this query and/or eliminate the derived table in the `WHERE EXISTS` clause, depending on the actual schema and what `table1` and `table2` represent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `EXISTS` to return a row if there exists a row with same name and location Shasta:

```
select name, location
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t1.name = t2.name
                and t2.locaion = 'Shasta')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do another subquery. I'll call the joinresult `joinedTable` as you didn't showed us the statement with which you build the table. But you can just switch the `joinedTable` for your statement. Then do

```
select * from joinedTable where name in (select name from joinedTable where location = 'Shasta');
```

Result is your wanted: 2x Bob, 3x Dylan

Heres a fiddle for it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7584e/3