# Exclude rows based on condition from two columns

Tags: clickhouse

My question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520964/sql-return-all-rows-where-at-least-one-has-value-y), except that I want to exclude all columns that have a unique value in a column.
If we assume that to be the input.

```
Name   |  Location
-------------------
Bob    |   Shasta
Bob    |   Leaves
Sean   |   Leaves
Sean   |   Leaves
Dylan  |   Shasta
Dylan  |   Redwood
Dylan  |   Leaves
```

I want the output to be

```
Name   |  Location
-------------------
Bob    |   Shasta
Bob    |   Leaves
Dylan  |   Shasta
Dylan  |   Redwood
Dylan  |   Leaves
```

In this case, Sean is being excluded because he always has the same location.
In SQL, there exists a subquery called whereexists. How do we do this in clickhouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT Name, Location
FROM (
  /* emulate the origin dataset */
  SELECT test_data.1 AS Name, test_data.2 AS Location
  FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([
      ('Bob', 'Shasta'),
      ('Bob', 'Leaves'),
      ('Sean', 'Leaves'),
      ('Sean', 'Leaves'),
      ('Dylan', 'Shasta'),
      ('Dylan', 'Redwood'),
      ('Dylan', 'Leaves')]) AS test_data))
WHERE Name IN (
  SELECT Name
  FROM (
    /* emulate the origin dataset */
    SELECT test_data.1 AS Name, test_data.2 AS Location
    FROM (
      SELECT arrayJoin([
        ('Bob', 'Shasta'),
        ('Bob', 'Leaves'),
        ('Sean', 'Leaves'),
        ('Sean', 'Leaves'),
        ('Dylan', 'Shasta'),
        ('Dylan', 'Redwood'),
        ('Dylan', 'Leaves')]) AS test_data))
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING uniq(Location) > 1)
/* result
┌─Name──┬─Location─┐
│ Bob   │ Shasta   │
│ Bob   │ Leaves   │
│ Dylan │ Shasta   │
│ Dylan │ Redwood  │
│ Dylan │ Leaves   │
└───────┴──────────┘
*/
```